# IIS Intranet Users Login

Tags: iis, iis-7, group-policy, windows-authentication, http-basic-authentication

I have a web application deployed in IIS 7. I want to configure it so that others from all intranet Domains can login to the web application. Here are the things I've done:

- Enabled IIS Windows Authentication
- I go to "lusrmgr.msc" Local Users and Groups, and I created a Group
- I added all the users from different Domains to the Group
- I go to "Local Security Policy"
- I added the Group to the "User Rights Assignment -> Access this computer from the network"
- I added the Group to the "User Rights Assignment -> Allow local login"

However when other users from different domain try to login they are still unable to login. Would like to ask advise what other things I should do or did I miss anything?

Please really need your advise as this is critical for us that other users can't login. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have them entering their fully qualified username? "DOMAIN\username" or username@DOMAIN

Comment: hi @GentlemanMax. The users are trying to enter "DOMAIN\username". The Group that I created contains members: "AP\Domain Users", "CN\Domain Users", "EU\Domain Users", "LA\Domain Users". I can login to the server of which I'm an admin using my Intranet ID or Email address. But the users can't login using intranet Id or their email addresses.